# How to capture global touch event in phaser.js

Tags: javascript, touch, phaser-framework

I need to do some actions after touch in any part of the screen. At this moment, I am using something like this:

```
update: function() {
    if (this.game.input.activePointer.isDown) {
        this.game.input.keyboard.onDownCallback = null;
        this.start();
    }
}
```

But I just don't feel it right, while I probably can use callbacks as I do with a keyboard:

```
 this.game.input.keyboard.onDownCallback = function(e){
        this.game.input.keyboard.onDownCallback = null;
        self.start();
    }
```

Is there any way to use callback on touch instead of checking in update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.game.input.onDown.add(function() {
    console.log("input captured");
});
```

As simple as that. It will work for mouse and for touch.

Comment: Thank you! It's actually THAT simple.